# Oracle XMLTable functions and XPATH

Tags: oracle, xquery

I have a following xml document stored in XML type table

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:200:tech:xsd:101" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <FIToFICstmrCdtTrf xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:200:tech:xsd:101">
                            <CreditTx>
                <PaymentID>
                    <InstrumentId>AAB000001</InstrumentId>
                    <Id>4730 2013-10-23 AAB000001</Id>
                    <TranxId>BULKTTXTDAAB000001</TranxId>
                </PaymentID>
            </CreditTx>
        </FIToFICstmrCdtTrf>
</Document>
```

When i execute the below SQL

```
SELECT payments.instrumentid,
payments.id,
payments.tranxid
FROM paymentxml,
XMLTable('for $i in /Document/FIToFICstmrCdtTrf/CreditTx/PaymentID
return $i'
PASSING OBJECT_VALUE
COLUMNS
instrumentid VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'InstrumentId' ,
id VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'Id' ,
tranxid VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'TranxId'
)payments
```

I get no results even though the xpath is correct any ideas what am i missing

Comment: You need to register the XML namespaces.

Comment: sorry can you elaborate please

Answer (score 0):

For the

> for $i in /Document/FIToFICstmrCdtTrf/CreditTx/PaymentID return $i

part you must give the doc as

> for $i in
>   doc("/your/path/your.xml")/Document/FIToFICstmrCdtTrf/CreditTx/PaymentID
>   return $i

it is important to know resources' location which is /your/path/your.xml

i hope this helps you.